# A mailing platform using Amazon SES and Node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a case where I need to implement a mailing platform using amazon SES. I have decided to do this using Node.js to achieve the desired concurrency.

Within the node js application, I would fetch all my contacts from a redis storage. 
What I specifically require is that I need to restrict the application from calling Amazon's api at a particular rate ,say x emails per second, or else I will be throttled by Amazon. Can any one please suggest me on how achieve this rate limiting using Node.js. I have tried the limiter package but couldn't follow the exact working. There isn't enough documentation available as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind that any solution that tries to limit the number of calls without considering the same type of node getting deployed twice or even more is really flawed. You can throttle the number of requests, but doing that in a distributed way is going to be much harder.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup that uses mongodb. Messages are queued into a collection by various apps and processed by a separate node app.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    _ = require('underscore') ;

var BATCH_SIZE = 50;
var INTERVAL = 60000;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/outbox');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    to: {type:String},
    subject: {type:String},
    body: {type:String},
    queued: {type:Date}

});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message',MessageSchema);

function processQueue(){
    var query = Message.find({}).sort({queued: -1}).limit(BATCH_SIZE);
    query.exec(function(err,messages){
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        if (!messages.length){
            console.log('Queue is empty');
        }else{
            _.each(messages,function(msg){
                 sendTheSESMessage(msg, function(success){
                     if (success){
                         //remove from queue
                         msg.remove();
                     }else{
                         //handle it
                     }
                 })
            });
        }
    });

}

setInterval(processQueue, INTERVAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:** [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) has already implemented something like this, take a look at the [throttle function](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

**EDIT:** I have made a module out of the code below, visit: https://github.com/gammasoft/rate-limited

---

This is a very simple implementation of something that might help you.

Params:
1. `params`: array with email addresses to be sent via SES
2. `fn`: function that will send a single email at a time
3. `timeout`: minimum time between each call to `fn`, in miliseconds, eg.: for 100 emails/sec then you pass `1000/100` (1 sec divided by 100 emails)
4. `callback`: function to be called when everything ends

**CODE**

```
// rate-limit.js
var async = require("async");

module.exports = function(params, fn, timeout, callback){
    var length = params.length;
    var wait = function(cb){
        if(--length === 0) return cb();
        else setTimeout(function(){
            cb();
        }, timeout);
    };

    async.eachSeries(params, async.compose(wait, fn), function(err){
        callback(err);
    });
};

module.exports.timesPerSecond = function(times){
    if(times === 0) throw new Error("Should not be zero");
    return 1000/times;
};

module.exports.timesPerMinute = function(times){
    if(times === 0) throw new Error("Should not be zero");
    return (60 * 1000)/times;
};
```

**USAGE**

```
//test.js
var rateLimited = require("./rate-limit.js");
var timesPerMinute = rateLimited.timesPerMinute; 
console.time("time");

rateLimited([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(name, cb){
    console.log(name);
    cb();
}, timesPerMinute(5), function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.timeEnd("time");
});
```

Comment: Note that underscore's _.throttle() function drops calls that exceed the allowed rate - perhaps not what we want when sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

**nodemailer** allegedly allows you to set a rate limit as an options parameter.

As stated in the [nodemailer-ses-transport doc](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-ses-transport):

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(sesTransport({
    accessKeyId: "AWSACCESSKEY",
    secretAccessKey: "AWS/Secret/key",
    rateLimit: 5 // do not send more than 5 messages in a second
}));
```

Once your transport object is set you can use it like so, by just adding mail options to construct your email (don't have to send html, see other options in **nodemailer** docs):

```
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'CompanyName <info@mycompany.com>',
    to: 'email@email.net',
    subject: 'This is a subject',
    html: '<h1>Some html here</h1>',
  };
```

and then send it:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        // handle error
    } else {
      // handle success
    } 
});
```

As you can see, it's pretty dead-easy to set up.